# Reading specific strings out of a file and printing several lines after

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to make a pseudo file manager, currently what I am trying to achieve is find an input term and printing it + the following 2 lines in the file. I have been just guessing my way into how to print it, it doesn't give me errors, it just closes automatically because it can't ind anything else to work with.
here's what i have

```
pl = []
        f_tn = "C:\\Users\\**\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\FileSerch\\Passwords.txt"
        exn = input("What term are you looking for? ")
        
        with open(f_tn, 'r') as nfp:
            y_fn = nfp.readlines()
            y_fn = [t.strip() for t in y_fn]
            stop_index = 0
            for i, element in enumerate(y_fn):
                if element == exn:
                    print(i, element)
                    stop_index = i+3
                    if i < stop_index:
                        pl.append(element)

#output
5 Discord
71 Discord
['Discord', 'Discord']
```

Comment: Can you share with us the file's contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple pointers...

Your indentation above is a bit whacky... unsure if it is just formatting.  Break the problem into steps.

1. get the string you are looking for
2. open the file and read contents either line-by-line or all at once
3. screen the results & print or store them as needed.

Recommend you use the `with open(...)` pattern for reading files.  You should research it a bit.

This works:

```
file = 'data.txt'
# f_tn = open("C:\\Users\\**\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\FileSerch\\Passwords.txt")

exn = input("What term are you looking for? ")

result = []

with open(file, 'r') as src:
    y_fn = src.readlines()
    print(y_fn)   # just for troubleshooting...can be removed

    # clean up the newline characters
    y_fn = [t.strip() for t in y_fn]

    # use your enumeration on y_fn, which holds the result of the read...
    stop_index = 0
    for i, element in enumerate(y_fn):
        if element == exn:
            # set up limit on i...
            stop_index = i+3
        if i < stop_index:
            result.append(element)

print(result)
```

#### mocked up data file:

```
bobby
123
abc
jimmy
678
def
sammy
998
ghi
```

#### Result:

```
What term are you looking for? jimmy
['bobby\n', '123\n', 'abc\n', 'jimmy\n', '678\n', 'def\n', 'sammy\n', '998\n', 'ghi']
['jimmy', '678', 'def']
```

Comment: Sorry took me a minute, stuff came up. So i tried this method but my only issue is that its not showing me the following lines, only the actual word in the file, the index changing doesnt seem to do anything to adjust it

Comment: The likely issue is with something in the format of your text file.  I left the troubleshooting print statement in the code above.  When you run this code on your file does it reproduce like mine does from the example?  (also, it would be helpful if you posted a snippet of your data file in your original post by editing it.)

Comment: I edit my code in the original so you can see what I changed, along with the results. I'm not sure what exactly could be happening in the text file to mess up. Aside from a new line of empty space under each name its just a big list file

Comment: OKAY I blanked on fixing and indent, thank you so much!!